# Make react-native-paper DataTable full width

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using the react-native-paper DataTable to create a calendar in react-native. However, i can't seem to get the table to take up 100% width, as pictured:
[image: calendar]

I have a basic setup like this:

```
            <DataTable>
                <DataTable.Row>
                    {weeks.map((day, index) => (
                        <DataTable.Cell >
                            <Text
                                key={`week-day-${index}`}
                            >
                            {dayjs(day).format("dd")}
                            </Text>
                        </DataTable.Cell>
                    ))}
                </DataTable.Row>
                {weeks.map((week, weekIndex) => (
                    <DataTable.Row
                        key={`week-${weekIndex}`}
                    >
                        {week.map((day, dayIndex) => (
                            <DataTable.Cell
                                key={`day-${dayIndex}`}
                            >
                                <Text>{day.getDate()}</Text>
                            </DataTable.Cell>
                        ))}
                    </DataTable.Row>
                ))}
            </DataTable>
```

How can i make the cells take up all the available space in that row?

Comment: Have you tried giving `DataTable.Row` a style with the width of 100%?

Comment: Yes, i've tried adding that to all the elements without luck

Comment: in App.js does your first view use a `flex:1`

Comment: No, cause then the whole view was squished at the top. Thank you though! I decided to make the calendar from scratch instead as i just couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your DataTable isnt taking up the entire width of the screen. The only reason I can imagine it not doing so is if its width is being limited by it parent components. I started working out some stuff for a calendar [here](https://snack.expo.dev/6UakM3H-f):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Text, DataTable,} from 'react-native-paper';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import TableHeader from './components/TableHeader';
import TableTitle from './components/TableTitle';
import SettingsModal from './components/SettingsModal';
import {
  wrapArray,
  getCalendarMonth,
  WEEK_DAYS,
} from './helpers/utils';

const currentDay = dayjs();

const pickerItems = WEEK_DAYS.map((day, i) => {
  return {
    label: day,
    value: i,
  };
});

export default function App() {
  // allow user to decide start of week
  const [weekStart, setWeekStart] = useState(0);
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(currentDay.get('month'));
  const [year, setYear] = useState(currentDay.get('year'));
  // when a month doesnt start at the weekStart it is necessary
  // add days or blanks to put the arrays  align days with the
  // proper week day
  const [hideExtraDays, setHideExtraDays] = useState(true);
  const [days, setDays] = useState(
    getCalendarMonth(month, year, weekStart, hideExtraDays)
  );

  const { weekDays, pickerList } = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      weekDays: wrapArray(WEEK_DAYS, weekStart),
      pickerList: wrapArray(pickerItems, weekStart),
    };
  }, [weekStart]);
  // incrementing/decrementing month is the same code
  // accessing different dayjs functions
  const incrementMonth = useCallback(
    (isDecrementing) => {
      const date = dayjs(`${year}-${month + 1}-01`);
      const functionKey = isDecrementing ? 'subtract' : 'add';
      const newDate = date[functionKey](1, 'month');
      setMonth(newDate.get('month'));
      setYear(newDate.get('year'));
    },
    [month, year]
  );
  // update days when these values change
  useEffect(() => {
    setDays(getCalendarMonth(month, year, weekStart, hideExtraDays));
  }, [weekStart, month, year, hideExtraDays]);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {/*modal for calendar settings */}
      <SettingsModal
        {...{
          pickerList,
          weekStart,
          setWeekStart,
          hideExtraDays,
          setHideExtraDays,
        }}
      />
      <View style={styles.calendarContainer}>
        <DataTable style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <TableTitle
            month={month}
            year={year}
            onLeftPress={() => incrementMonth(true)}
            onRightPress={() => incrementMonth()}
            // the month and year is a pressable that when press reveal
            // dropdown flatlist picker on android this picker is unscrollable
            onDateChange={(date) => {
              setMonth(date.month);
              setYear(date.year);
            }}
          />
          {/* days of the week */}
          <TableHeader weekDays={weekDays} />
          {days.map((week, weekIndex) => (
            <DataTable.Row key={`week-${weekIndex}`}>
              {week.map((day, dayIndex) => (
                <DataTable.Cell key={`day-${dayIndex}`}>
                  {/* hideExtra days add null values when true */}
                  <Text>{day ? day.get('date') : null}</Text>
                </DataTable.Cell>
              ))}
            </DataTable.Row>
          ))}
        </DataTable>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  calendarContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I decided to make the calendar from scratch insted though as i just couldn't get it to work

Comment: If you aren't making the calendar for educational purposes, then here's a pretty customizable calendar https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars